# abort execution of a stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have a db2 stored proc which contains a select query. I want to abort or fail this stored proc if the select query is returning any value. Please help.

```
SET CURRENT SCHEMA = abc;
SET CURRENT PATH = abc,pqr;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc.VALID_xyz ( )
  SPECIFIC SQL150421070712734
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  EXTERNAL ACTION
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
begin
DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN
            FOR select * from xy_table;           
open C1;    
RETURN;
END;
SET CURRENT SCHEMA = abc;
```

If xy_table has any rows , I need to fail this stored proc.

Comment: If your procedure isn't actually manipulating something outside of DB2, (e.g. a Java object in a JVM) it will help if you let the DB2 procedure compiler know that by specifying `NO EXTERNAL ACTION` instead of the more cautious default value of `EXTERNAL ACTION`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SIGNAL`command can trigger a predefined or custom SQLSTATE that will abort the current SQL procedure (or atomic block of SQL statements) as if an actual error had occurred.

```
SET CURRENT SCHEMA = abc;
SET CURRENT PATH = abc,pqr;

--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc.valid_xyz()
SPECIFIC valid_xyz
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM xy_table FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75002' 
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 
           'Table XY_TABLE contained data when it was expected to be empty.';
     END IF;
END@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;

CALL valid_xyz();

SQL0438N  Application raised error or warning with diagnostic text: 
"Table XY_TABLE contained data when it was expected to be empty.".  SQLSTATE=75002
```